# Pass user input vector to a function that takes a string

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny

I have a shiny app that takes in user input:
`input$libraries` is a reactive character vector produced by user input from

```
output$libraries <- renderUI({
checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "libraries", 
                   label = strong("Select the libraries for which you would like to see part counts"), 
                   choiceValues = LibraryIDs$libraryid,
                   choiceNames = LibraryNames$name, 
                   selected = LibraryIDs$libraryid[1],
                   inline = T)}})
})
```

I would like to select from my postgreSQL database, I have a function set up as such:

```
get_query <- function(querystring){
  # create a connection

  # loads the PostgreSQL driver
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "RosettaRelational",
                   host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                   user = "postgres", password = rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password"))
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))

  # check for the existance of tables, must be created in pgAdmin4
  #dbExistsTable(con, "libraries")

  query <- eval(parse(text = querystring))
  return(query)
}
```

It takes in a string and parses it to evaluate the query

now when I try to query the database as such:

```
Names <- get_query(paste0("con %>% tbl('libraries') %>% 
filter(libraryid %in% input$libraries) %>% select(name) %>% collect()"))
```

I get the error: object 'input' not found. I know it's not parsing the reactive character vector correctly. How should I change this to get it to work?

I tried:

```
Names <- get_query(paste0("con %>% tbl('libraries') %>% 
filter(libraryid %in% '",input$libraries,"') %>% select(name) %>% collect()"))
```

but that only selects the first library in the vector even when the user selects multiple libraries..this works when input$ is only one character, for example when the input is an action button instead of checkboxes

basically what I need is for `input$libraries` to look like c('111a,'111b','211','311a') when it is passed into the string if user selects 111a, 111b, 211 and 311a, instead of just '111a' which is what it is currently passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from some testing on my side that your code

```
Names <- get_query(paste0("con %>% tbl('libraries') %>% filter(libraryid %in% '",input$libraries,"') %>% select(name) %>% collect()"))
```

will "vectorise" in its current form for multiple libraries in `input$libraries`. This will create a separate string for each library in input$libraries instead of one string containing all libraries. e.g.

```
> Names
[1] "con %>% tbl('libraries') %>% filter(libraryid %in% '111a') %>% select(name) %>% collect()" 
[2] "con %>% tbl('libraries') %>% filter(libraryid %in% '111b') %>% select(name) %>% collect()"
```

Using my own data and your suggestion "for `input$libraries` to look like c('111a','111b','211','311a')" I adapted your code to

```
Names <- get_query(paste0("con %>% tbl('libraries') %>% filter(libraryid %in% c(", paste0("'", input$libraries, "'", collapse = ", "), ")) %>% select(name) %>% collect()"))
```

This should give you your required c('111a', '111b', '211', '311a').

It's not the most elegant but it should work. You could also do that inner `paste0()` before if it looks messy, as below

```
libraries_comma_separated <- paste0("'", input$libraries, "'", collapse = ", ")
```

This will give you '111a', '111b', '211', '311a' and then do

```
Names <- get_query(paste0("con %>% tbl('libraries') %>% filter(libraryid %in% c(", libraries_comma_separated, ")) %>% select(name) %>% collect()"))
```

Comment: I was sooo close! I had figured out how to get it to look like c('111a, '111b', '211', '311a'), but probably because of a simple syntax error somewhere it was still giving me an error when passed into the string..
what you did worked, and was my logic too but somehow I wasn't executing correctly..Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, really glad to have helped. I had used similar code before which made it easier. Syntax always gets you and it's often difficult to debug.